# compare different elements (if we have the same base letter)

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function allow to compare some elements like   `accélérer, Accelerer, ACCELERER...etc`  and return True as result (if we have the same base letter).

example:

```
compare('accélérer','ACCELERER')  // will be true
compare('accélérer','accelerer')  // will be true
compare('accélérer','test')  // will be false
```

thanks

Comment: Do you want to treat "é" and "e" as the same letter? And do you distinguish cases (uppercase and lowercase)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Sounds easy enough, (stringA.toLowerCase().replace("é", "e").compare(stringB.toLowerCase().replace("é", "e")) == 0) ? true : false;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), try this:

```js
const compare = (a, b)  => !a.localeCompare(b, 'en' , { sensitivity: 'base'})

console.log(compare('accélérer','ACCELERER'))   
console.log(compare('accélérer','accelerer')) 
console.log(compare('accélérer','test'))
```